# Problemas creando una función decoradora dentro de una clase en Python3

Tags: python-3.x

Hola buenas recientemente he estado practicando un poco sobre las funciones decoradoras y he estado tratando de implementarla dentro de una función al intentar hacerlo me he empezado a topar con un que otro problema

```
import time

class Reporte:
    def __init__(self):
        self.reportes = []
    def documentar(funcion):
        def envoltorio():
            self.reportes.append(f"{funcion.__name__} started at {time.ctime()}")
            resultado = funcion()
            self.reportes.append(f"{funcion.__name__} finished at {time.ctime()} and returned {resultado}")
            return resultado
        return envoltorio

    

@Reporte.documentar
def nombre():
    print(f"Hola, {input("Cual es su nombre?")}")


nombre()
```

lo que quiero hacer acá es appendar a una lista llamada "self.reportes" un texto dentro de la funcion reporte

```
self.reportes.append(f"{funcion.__name__} started at {time.ctime()}")
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

ya probé añadiendole "self" en ambos appends y no me terminó funcionando, ya intenté creando el decorador antes del init

Comment: No agregaste `self` como parámetro, no tiene modo de encontrar la variable.

Comment: @Mateo si hago eso me devuelve error no me deja decorar, me dice que tengo un parametro de mas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu lista `reportes` es un atributo de [instancia](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects).
Para acceder a ella necesitas instanciar la clase `Reporte`.
Por eso has hecho bien al escribir `self.reportes` dentro de la función `documentar`.
Sin embargo dentro de la función `documentar` no está definida la variable `self`: necesita recibirla como argumento.
Por lo tanto deberías modificar la llamada a la función para que reciba un primer argumento que por convención llamamos `self`.
Lectura recomendada: [Algunas observaciones sobre clases](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks)

El código modificado quedará:

```py
    def documentar(self, funcion):
```

Ahora que `documentar` es una función miembro, necesitas una instancia de `Reporte`.
Esto es así porque tu lista `reportes` sólo existe tras llamar al método [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__).
Cuando escribes `Reporte.documentar` estás tratando de acceder al método sin proporcionar una instancia.
Podrías crear una instancia y después usar llamar a su decorador:

```py
# Creo una instancia
reporte = Reporte()

# Utilizo el decorador
@reporte.documentar
def nombre(): ...

# Llamo a la función
nombre()

# Imprimo todos los reportes
print(*reporte.reportes, sep="\n")
```

---

Otra opción es evitar la variable global `reporte` y guardar la lista `reportes` como una [variable de clase](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables).
En ese caso no escribiremos método `__init__` y en su lugar definimos `reportes` así:

```py
class Reporte:
    reportes = []
```

Ahora, como no tienes método `__init__`, tus métodos no serán de instancia: serán de clase o [estáticos](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod).
En ambos casos ya no escribiremos el primer argumento como `self`.
Para las funciones de clase usaremos el decorador [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#classmethod).
Lo cual quedará:

```
class Reporte:
    reportes = []

    @classmethod
    def documentar(cls, funcion):
        def envoltorio():
            cls.reportes.append(f"{funcion.__name__} started at {time.ctime()}")
            resultado = funcion()
            cls.reportes.append(f"{funcion.__name__} finished at {time.ctime()} and returned {resultado}")
            return resultado
        return envoltorio
```

Para utilizarlo:

```py
# Utilizo el decorador, que es un método de clase
@Reporte.documentar
def nombre(): ...

# Llamo a la función
nombre()

# Imprimo todos los reportes
print(*Reporte.reportes, sep="\n")
```